# How to save FB reactions SVG animation?

Tags: facebook, svg

I'm trying to get a hold of the SVG animation that occurs when you hover over the like button on Facebook. I cannot find the animated version in the code. I basically want to extract one if possible and have it run offline. It looks like this:

http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/ab614b29e3cee096e557141d52bcfde5/202776437/2015-10-08+18_12_22.gif

Really appreciate any insight here. This is the code I was able to find, but it doesn't seem to animate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to make your own SMIL animations?
Look at the demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/09aLov71/2/
It's not perfect but it gives you an idea. For more documentation, you can see here: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-smil/

```
<circle r=15 fill="yellow"/>
<circle r=0 cy="6" fill="white">
  <animate 
    id="a1"
    begin="icon.mouseenter"
    attributeName="r"
    values="0;8"
    dur="0.5s"
    fill="freeze"
    />
  <animate 
    id="a2"
    begin="a1.end"
    attributeName="r"
    values="8;4;7;3;8"
    dur="1s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    fill="freeze"/>
  <animate 
    id="a3"
    to="0"
    begin="icon.mouseleave"
    attributeName="r"
    repeatCount="1"
    dur="1s"
    fill="freeze"/>
</circle>
<circle cx="-5" cy="-2" r="2" fill="black">
  <animate begin="a1.begin" values="-2;-6" attributeName="cy" fill="freeze" dur="0.5s"/>
  <animate begin="a1.begin" values="-5;-8" attributeName="cx" fill="freeze" dur="0.5s"/>
  <animate begin="a3.begin" to="-2" attributeName="cy" fill="freeze" dur="1s"/>
  <animate begin="a3.begin" to="-5" attributeName="cx" fill="freeze" dur="1s"/>
</circle>
<circle cx="5" cy="-2" r="2" fill="black">
  <animate begin="a1.begin" values="-2;-6" attributeName="cy" fill="freeze" dur="0.5s"/>
  <animate begin="a1.begin" values="5;8" attributeName="cx" fill="freeze" dur="0.5s"/>
  <animate begin="a3.begin" to="-2" attributeName="cy" fill="freeze" dur="1s"/>
  <animate begin="a3.begin" to="5" attributeName="cx" fill="freeze" dur="1s"/>
</circle>
```